# Uncaught module <plugin ID> not found for cordova 3.6.3

Tags: cordova

I have followed all specified steps in https://github.com/Red-Folder/bgs-core/wiki/Build-your-own-Background-Service.when i try to use ***cordova.require('com.*.tmService')***this in my index.js file, i get "Uncaught module  not found".

```
I INSTALLED PLUGIN BY THESE STEPS:

1.cordova  plugin add com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice
2.added tmService.java in com.* package.
3.defined service in android mainfest.xml.

Please help me in resolving this plugin issue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was because of explicitly declaring js/cordova.js in my index.html.JUST include cordova.js in the index.html.Cordova.js need not be there physically under www folder.cordova lib will take care of the cordova.js.